# Function to print not working

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on creating a video game using Javascript and my knowledge is pretty basic. I'm trying to create a function that will be used to create all the sprites as well as print them to  a canvas, but when I try to print them nothing works. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is or if I'm doing the whole thing wrong entirely. Below is my current code.

```
//Gets canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Creates all attributes of sprite
function sprite(imageName, imageX, imageY, imageHeight, imageWidth){
    this.imageName = imageName;
    this.imageX = imageX;
    this.imageY = imageY;
    this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
    this.imageWidth = imageWidth;

    this.draw = function(){
        character = new Image();
        character.src = "../Images/" + this.imageName + ".png";
        character.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(character, this.imageX, this.imageY,  this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
        }
    };

    this.getHeight = function(){
        return this.imageHeight;
    };

    this.getWidth = function(){
        return this.imageWidth;
    };

    this.getX = function(){
        return this.imageX;
    };

    this.getY = function(){
        return this.imageY;
    };

    this.moveUpX = function(e){
        this.imageX = (this.imageX + e);
    };

    this.moveUpY = function(f){
        this.imageY = (this.imageY + e);
    };

    this.moveBackX = function(e){
        this.imageX = (this.imageX - e);
    };

    this.moveBackY = function(f){
        this.imageY = (this.imageY - e);
    };

    this.changeImage = function(a){
        this.imageName = a;
    };

    this.getImage = function(){
        return imageName;
    };

    this.changeX = function(b){
        this.imageX = b;
    };

    this.changeY = function(c){
        this.imageY = c;
    };

}

//Creates Sprite
sprites[0] = new sprite('mySprite', 0, 0, 36, 51);
sprites[0].draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sprites` var is undefined. You need to define that first

```
var sprites = []; // add this line
sprites[0] = new sprite('mySprite', 0, 0, 36, 51);
sprites[0].draw();
```